# Open ie from command line invisibly

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

I'm trying to open internet explorer invisibly frim command line. The page I will open log user data for our software. Thats why I want to make it invisible, there is nothing necessary for people on the page.

I tried this,

```
start iexplore http://www.example.com
```

it works. However, its visible.  (I know there are some working scripts in vbs , shell. But I need to make it from command line) How to make it invisible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't with batch.

This is a vbs script. Just execute it.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run """c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore"" www.google.com", 0, false
```

Comment: The problem with this is that when you add the bat file (which runs this vbs) doesnt do the job. What could be the reason ?

Comment: How do you know, it's invisible. Say what happened. We can't deal with generalities.

Comment: Show the batch file - we really have no idea what you are doing and can't test the issue without information.